# Solving nonlinear PDE

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following partial differential equation

$$ u_t = \frac{\alpha u_x^2}{u_{xx}} + \beta x u_x, $$

where $u_{xx} < 0$ and $u(T, x) = e^{- \rho T} x^{1 - \gamma}$ for arbitrary constants $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \rho$ and $T$ in $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$. Thought, I haven't been able to deal with the non-linearity caused by $u_{xx}$ via numerical methods. This kind of equation comes from stochastic optimal control problems, but in this specific case it seems easier to solve via the PDE. I have tried to use NDSolve as following to solve the equation

```
alfa = 1; beta = 1; gamma = 0.5; T = 1; rho = 0;

sol = First@NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] == alfa*(D[u[x, t], x]^2)/(D[u[x, t], x, x]) + beta*x*D[u[x, t], x], u[x, T] == exp(-rho * T)*x^(1 - gamma)}, DirichletCondition[D[u[x,t], x, x] < 0, True] u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}];

Plot3D[u[x, t] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, t, u}];
```

But several errors are caused, one because it can't be written in terms of the inactive form as [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1484968070). I haven't been able to solve via neither other method found in similar questions.

Comment: `exp(-rho * T)` should be `Exp[-rho * T]`

Comment: I am no expert in differential equations, but isn't a Dirichlet condition applied to the value of the function itself, rather than its derivative? And doesn't that only apply to the boundary, rather than everywhere on the domain?